# Does EclipseFP Haskell outline view work?

Tags: eclipse, haskell, eclipse-plugin

I'm using [EclipseFP](http://eclipsefp.sourceforge.net/) for editing my Haskell project. It's works very well as far as syntax colouring and building and running the code, but the outline view for a module is always empty.  Should it work? And if so, what do I need to look at to fix it?

I'm using the latest versions -  Haskell Platform with GHC 7.0.3 and EclipseFP 2.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through the web myself I cannot find any reference to a module outline view in EclipseFP specifically. There are articles/posts [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsefp/forums/forum/371922/topic/3965795) and [here](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t62769.rhtml) but they only refer to outlining for the file structure.

Unfortunately, I suspect that at the moment, based on looking through development articles (including those above) and relevant EclipseFP sites that EclipseFP probably only supports standard file outlining and not module outlining for the moment. Sorry, looks like you're going to have to wait a while longer.

Comment: Still, eclipse is a step up from GEdit which is what we had to use for our exams...

Comment: You can ask questions about EclipseFP on the actual sourceforge forum or on github, you may get quicker answers. Anyway for that particular issue, EclipseFP DOES provide a outline view of the module, showing data and constructors, functions, etc. If it's not working, turn on debug mode and check for errors. Also, EclipseFP is updated regularly, so check out the latest version!